# How Do You Add An EventHandler to a Dynamically Loaded DLL?

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, dll

I have a DLL which contains a usercontrol.

I am loading the DLL and the usercontrol dynamically but can't seem to figure out how to add the various event handlers.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

The code to load the DLL and control is as follows

```
Dim _ReportBuilderDLL As System.Reflection.Assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("[FullPath]\ReportBuilder.dll")
Dim _ReportBuilderCtlType As Type = _ReportBuilderDLL.GetType("ReportBuilder.ReportBuilderControl")
Dim _ReportBuilderCtl As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(_ReportBuilderCtlType)

_ReportBuilderCtl.CancelButtonVisible = True
_ReportBuilderCtl.Size = ListBoxControl1.Size
_ReportBuilderCtl.Location = ListBoxControl1.Location

XtraTabPage2.Controls.Add(_ReportBuilderCtl)
```

After this has run I want to add the event handler named CancelPressed.

It has the parameters sender as object and e as MouseEventArgs

Could anyone help me?
Thanks

**EDIT**

I almost forgot, I tried adding an eventhandler as follows but got an error.

```
Dim _Event As EventInfo = _ReportBuilderCtlType.GetEvent("CancelPressed")
_Event.AddEventHandler(Me, New reportbuilderuc_CancelPressedDel(AddressOf reportbuilderuc_CancelPressed))
```

The error said "System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type"

Comment: `AddHandler _ReportBuilderCtl.YOURMETHODFROMDLL, AddressOf CancelPressed`... On another note, why manually and not just add it as a reference, also turn `Option Strict On`...

Comment: That doesn't work. As you can see the _ReportBuilderCtl is an object, so it doesn't have any events. So when you try to compile, it errors.

Comment: Thats why I mentioned `Turn Option Strict On`... then fix your issues and then you would have events :)

Comment: Also, I'm not adding it as a reference as I am trying to reduce the amount of memory being used.

Comment: That's a wrong assumption, if adding it as a reference and or calling it from code it still allocates the memory for the library....

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just add this dll as a normal reference? If you cant access the exact type then can you cast it to a base class / interface and which has the event declared

Comment: Sorry, you were replying while I was adding my second comment. It still doesn't work, for the exact same reason. There are no events because it is an object.

Comment: @FloatingKiwi thats why I told him to turn `Option Strict On` fix his errors and he would have what he needed :)

Comment: @SteMoore you need to cast it, thats what I am saying. When you turn `Option Strict On` you would clearly see this! Also if there are no events in your dll you need to create one to use it :)

Comment: Yes, listen to what we ***are trying to explain to you***...

Comment: Ok..  @Zaggler I've set Option Strict On and it reacts the same as without it on. Could you possibly tell me how I am to cast a usercontrol as a usercontrol that is not within the project?

Comment: @FloatingKiwi I had the DLL referenced in a project and it was leaving it open when I disposed of it and set it as nothing. I couldn't explain it and decided to load it an runtime, then unload it when I had finished with it.

Comment: I think you'll regret taking this path in the long run and I'm sceptical about it resolving your issues. If you need to do dynamic load  / unload an appdomain may be your best choice. If you're committed to doing it this way I'm sure you could reflect the event but I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: Or your could add an interface in a common project. Then cast to the interface type

Comment: Is it not possible to add an event handler to a dynamically loaded DLL?

Comment: It is please read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228976(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Passing `Me` is wrong, you have to pass a reference to the object that generates the event.  So pass `_ReportBuilderCtl` instead.